# Android Bluetooth LE: Not discovering services after connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to use Android's Bluetooth Low Energy to communicate with a BLE device.  The first time I connect, everything works fine (connecting to GATT server works, all services and characteristics are discovered, etc.)  But, if I disconnect and try to re-connect, it will connect to the GATT server, but will not be able to discover the services.  I have to kill the app and restart it, and sometimes even that doesn't work.

This is the code I'm using to disconnect from the device:

```
public void close(View view) {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}
```

Is there anything else that I need to do when disconnecting?  There seems to be some resource that is still connected that prevents discovery of services when I try and reconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution: you need to call both `BluetoothGatt.disconnect()` AND `BluetoothGatt.close()`.

Comment: Technically, you need to call BluetoothGatt.disconnect() and then [because onConnectionStateChange isn't guaranteed to be called] start a timer and then either wait for onConnectionStateChange state=STATE_DISCONNECTED or the timeout, and then call BluetoothGatt.close()

Comment: @swooby is there a source you could provide that mentions the need to wait for STATE_DISCONNECTED before calling close? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I haven't observed that trace in my logs even though I call disconnect right before close. Then again, I'm looking at nougat right now. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You can definitely call close directly after disconnect. The only bad thing that could happen is that a warning is printed in the log. The only thing you should avoid is calling disconnect or close immediately after connectGatt since those calls might be ignored due to internal race conditions.